# How do you prevent uas and usb_storage kernel modules from being automatically loaded when a USB flash drive is connected?

Tags: kernel-modules, usb-drive, buildroot

I generate a kernel Image using buildroot that I put onto an SD card to boot from.  In buildroot I modularized USB Mass Storage.  When I boot up my board without a USB connected to it I can see that no modules are running by using `lsmos`.  But the instant I plug my USB in, the modules `uas` and `usb_storage` automatically load and allow access to the USB.  I want to prevent this and only allow access to the USB if I manually load in those two modules.

I have read a few articles online about blacklisting the modules or editing files related to the modules; however, this doesn't work because any changes I make are erased when I power off.  So I need another option that is permanent, perhaps done in the buildroot settings prior to generating the Image?

Comment: Have a look at `udev` and `systemd-udevd.service`. Or see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Using_files_in_.2Fetc.2Fmodprobe.d.2F_2 : "Note: The blacklist command will blacklist a module so that it will not be loaded automatically, but the module may be loaded if another non-blacklisted module depends on it or if it is loaded manually. "

Comment: @PatrickMevzek the problem is that there is no modprobe.d file.  All of the examples I have found (like this one) make assumptions that do not exist on my end

Comment: `modprobe.conf` would do the same IIRC or you can created `/etc/modprobe.d/` it is just a way for humans to organize stuff and applications to drop files with their own rules their.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem is that by default, busybox’ implementation of modprobe (which is used in buildroot) does not support `blacklist`.

The solution is to enable this feature in the busybox config when compiling the image. To do this, create a config fragment file, e.g. called `busybox.config`, with the following contents:

```
CONFIG_FEATURE_MODPROBE_BLACKLIST=y
```

Then, add the path to this file to the buildroot option. In the buildroot config file, it should look similar to this:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES="../busybox.config"
```

Now, when you run `make`, you will see that the buildroot make process is rebuilding busybox‘ config file. Watch out for the modprobe output, it should look like this:

```
modprobe (28 kb) (MODPROBE) [Y/n/?] y
  Blacklist support (FEATURE_MODPROBE_BLACKLIST) [Y/n/?] y
```

After doing this, you can just write `blacklist <themodule>` into `/etc/modprobe.conf` and it works as expected.